# How can I set an image from a file path?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I'm saving an image from the device's camera to a directory on the SD card (ex: `/sdcard/appName/image.jpg`), then I save the path into a database. My problem is that I can't seem to load the images into a `ListView` with a cursor adapter.

I tried the following code, where `helper.getImg();` is a method from my database helper that returns a `String` (the file path), but it is not working.

```
icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon_pura);
String imgPath=helper.getImg(c);
Bitmap myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
icon.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer has to do with URIs, and you need to use the `externalstorage()` function. Using set paths won't work on every device

anyway you store path into the URI which is more flexible for retrieving and parsings items at that path

Answer (score 0):

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Directory name/";
File file = new File(filepath,imagename);
FileInputStream fs = null;
try 
{
    fs = new FileInputStream(file);
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            /*
             * bfOptions.inDither=false; //Disable Dithering mode
             * bfOptions.inPurgeable=true; //Tell to gc that whether it needs
             * free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
             * bfOptions.inInputShareable=true;*/

bfOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
bfOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];
try {
    Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fs.getFD(), null,bfOptions);
    icon.setImageBitmap(originalImage);
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow himanshu's (correct) advice, make sure that if you're going to allow the user the option of loading and re-loading the image, make sure to manually icon.setImageBitmap(null); between loads, because otherwise Android will leak that memory and you'll crash your app.  It's not 100% consistant, and has something to do with the sizes of the images you're loading, but I just found this leak a few days ago and am 100% certain that it's there.